# Creation of Multiple Message Queues, with Unique Keys for the queues

Tags: c, unix, ipc

We create multiple queues for message passing from one process to other. But sometimes the keys of the message queues get overlapped ( same keys for separate queues). In order to avoid this I thought of using IPC_PRIVATE with the function msgget() which is used in the creation of Message queues.

This [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html) says I should use IPC_PRIVATE, My application is critical so I have to avoid the current situation.
syntax of this msgget is *int msgget(key_t key, int msgflg);*. 
Please tell me the syntax for msgget with IPC_PRIVATE and wether it will solve my issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please tell me the syntax for msgget with IPC_PRIVATE

`IPC_PRIVATE` is a value of type `key_t`.  You pass it as the literal key value:

```
int flags = /* ... permission bits ... */;
int my_mq = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, flags);
```

You do not need to include `IPC_CREAT` or `IPC_EXCL` among the flags when you use `IPC_PRIVATE`; if you do include them then they will be ignored.

> and wether it will solve my issue ?

Every successful call to `msgget()` with key `IPC_PRIVATE` creates a new message queue and returns its identifier, so this approach will definitely prevent inadvertent queue sharing.  It also, however, makes it harder to perform *intentional* queue sharing, and that may present its own issue for you.  After all, message queues are an IPC mechanism, so it seems likely that you do want certain processes to share queues.  Facilitating that is the whole point of key-based queue access.

As an alternative, the usual way to access queues revolves around generating keys with `ftok()`, based on a distinguishing well-known or computable file name.  The file name might be that of a working directory, a central executable, or a configuration file.  By appropriate choice of the distinguishing file, different groups of cooperating executables can obtain different keys.  The second parameter to `ftok()` enables cooperating processes to generate (the same) set of up to 256 common keys.

Comment: Thanks, But used IPC_EXCL served my purpose as, I didn't wished to msgget to return the existing queue id on call. IPC_EXCL helped me to fail the call if msg qid is existing for that key. If not it will create the new msg qid, serving the cause to avoid overlaps (using the same msg queues for different threads/processes ) .